# Generating a subquery with Arel to get an average of averages

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, aggregate, arel

Lets say I have a few of tables

```
orders = Arel::Table.new :orders
stores = Arel::Table.new :stores
managers = Arel::Table.new :managers
```

And a manager has many stores and a store has many orders.

One day I want to query for the average total across orders where a manager works. Oh, I want to group that by the store. So to be clear, I want to get the average order total for a manager, for each of the stores they work at.

And let's assume we've looked up our manager:

```
manager = Manager.find(some_id)


totals = orders.where(orders[:store_id].in(manager.store_ids)).group(orders.store_id).project(orders[:total].average)

puts totals.to_sql

"SELECT AVG(`orders`.`total`) AS avg_id FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`store_id` IN (1, 2, 3) GROUP BY `orders`.`store_id`"
```

Yup, that works great. But how can I get a query for the average of those averages?

What's the Arel to get this query?

```
"SELECT AVG(avg_id) FROM (SELECT AVG(`orders`.`total`) AS avg_id FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`store_id` IN (1, 2, 3) GROUP BY `orders`.`store_id`) as avg_id_alias;"
```

Anybody know?

Answer (score 3):

You can get pretty close, but ActiveRecord doesn't support the execution of Arel structures directly, you have to convert them to SQL first.

Here's an example of something similar to what you're doing:

```
o = Orders.arel_table
o_avg = Orders.select(:avg[:store_id].as('avg_id')).
              where(:store_id => [1,2,3]).group(:store_id)

Orders.find_by_sql("select avg(avg_id) from (#{o_avg.to_sql})")
```

Be happy with this compromise. ActiveRecord is poorly suited to gather aggregate data *about* more than one model at a time, and if you wisely are leery of patching SQL together, then Arel can server as an adequate tool for it.

Comment: Or you can (maybe) use AREL completelly. See my gist on heavy SQL. https://gist.github.com/foton/9cc80c5d85c274fb08af17699536a516

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question up on Forrst - there are a couple of answers here, but they look like workarounds:

[Nested queries in Arel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894807/nested-queries-in-arel)

[Building a subquery with ARel in Rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542684/building-a-subquery-with-arel-in-rails3)

Isn't this a key failing of ORM? For anything above rudimentary SQL calls - either the database gets compromised to appease the ORM, or conversely we have to convert the SQL into AQL,BQL,CQL (insert proprietary ORM fluid interface here).

Comment: It's not a failing of ORM in principle. It's a failing of certain ORM implementations.