# Rails 3, Cannot visit Arel::SelectManager

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope, rails-activerecord, arel

I have user model with `:except_ids` scope:

```
scope :except_ids, ->(*ids) { where { id.not_in ids } }
```

The problem is - I can't use it with another lazy queries. For example, if I call something like this:

```
User.except_ids(User.except_ids(1,2))
```

I end up with

```
TypeError: Cannot visit Arel::SelectManager
```

I have much more complex query in my project, but everything works fine - except that scope.
I can make it work by replacing scope by actual code, but that smells.

So, is there any way to find this out?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve this with a single SQL query, it has to contain a [subquery](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm), which is not directly supported by Arel, but you can use [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5355077/103160), for example.

The error you see is probably caused by the fact, that `User.except_ids(1,2)` returns an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which may be a problem for the splat operator in the signature of the lambda. This works, but results in 2 queries:

```
User.except_ids(User.except_ids(1,2).map(&:id))
```

Comment: Well, the thing is, map(&:id) will load results for relation inside brackets. The point of all my manipulations is to generate one giant query.

Comment: For greater efficiency with the double-query solution, use pluck rather than map: `User.except_ids(User.except_ids(1,2).pluck('id'))`. This produces a `SELECT id` rather than a `SELECT *`, and returns it in an array with only the ids.